# How to attach a field to an entity programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to attach a field to an entity programmatically?

I want to create a new entity, say vehicle, which has radio buttons defined for the brand of the vehicle. I would like this field to not be able to be deleted or modified via the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, the function is [field_create_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7).
If the field was not created before, you will need to create it with [field_create_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) first.

Comment: Thanks! I also found this, which looks to be helpful: http://drupal.org/node/1228878

Comment: Add field to entity programmatically in Drupal 7: http://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/add-field-entity-programmatically-drupal-7

Comment: The function is `field_create_instance()` if anyone tries to copy and paste. I tried to edit the post but edits must be at least 6 characters.